# Ошибка динамического массива C#

Tags: c#, массивы

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static unsafe void Main()
    {

        string houses_number;
        int summ_chet = 0, summ_nechet = 0, g = 0, g1 = 0, str;
        Console.Write("Введите количество домов: ");
        houses_number = Console.ReadLine();
        str = Convert.ToInt32(houses_number);

       int []houses = new int[str];
        int []people = new int[str];

        var searchHousse = str;

        var indexOfHouse = Array.IndexOf(houses, searchHousse);

        for (int i = 0; i < str; i++)
        {
            var r = i + 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Количество жителей в доме № "+r+": ");

            people[i] = Console.Read();

        }

        int max = people[0];
        int min = people[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < str; i++)
        {

            if (indexOfHouse%2==0)
            {
                summ_chet += people[i];
            }
            else
            {
                summ_nechet += people[i];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < str; i++)
        {

            if (i % 2==0)
            {

                if (people[i] < min)
                {
                    min = people[i];
                }
            }

            else
            {

                if (people[i] > max)
                {
                    max = people[i];
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Количество людей на четной стороне: "+summ_chet);
        Console.WriteLine("Количество людей на нечетной стороне: " + summ_nechet);
        if (summ_chet > summ_nechet)
            Console.WriteLine("На четной стороне находится больше людей.");
        else if (summ_chet < summ_nechet)
            Console.WriteLine("На нечетной стороне находится больше людей.");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("На четной стороне находится столько же людей, сколько и на нечетной.");
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не работает цикл, нужно, чтобы он заполнялся, но происходит то, что на фото.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замени `people[i] = Console.Read();` на это `people[i] = Convert.TonInt32(Console.ReadLine());`